# Python Beautiful Soup Web Scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have utilised beautiful soup and the class_ to web scrape. When I used find it was ok as I could use get.text() to find the text within the tags. However I want several of the values that are in the following below.

```
boal_data = boal_soup(class_="investment-info__item grid__item lap--1-2 desk--1-2")
print (boal_data)
```

This then produces, when you print, the following.

```
[<div class="investment-info__item grid__item lap--1-2 desk--1-2">
<h2 class="fontsize--p">Investment Date</h2>
<p class="fontsize--h3">Apr 2018</p>
</div>, <div class="investment-info__item grid__item lap--1-2 desk--1-2">
<h2 class="fontsize--p">Country</h2>
<p class="fontsize--h3">Netherlands</p>
</div>, <div class="investment-info__item grid__item lap--1-2 desk--1-2">
<h2 class="fontsize--p">Revenue at ACQ.</h2>
<p class="fontsize--h3">€156m</p>
</div>, <div class="investment-info__item grid__item lap--1-2 desk--1-2">
<h2 class="fontsize--p">Employees at ACQ.</h2>
<p class="fontsize--h3">370</p>
</div>]
```

I would like to be able to extra the following.

```
<p class="fontsize--h3">[this text here] </p>
```

How am I able to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [find](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) or [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to get text of paragraph tag.
You can try this

```
soup.find_all("p","fontsize--h3").getText()
```

Comment: Without the .get_text() that gives me what I want however when I do .get_text() on the end I receive the following error: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: find_all() returns a list so you can't call .get_text(). You either pick an item from the list and call .get_text() or you use find() which will get you only the first result.